# Hooking up generator to house propane supply

Tags: generator, propane

I have a dual fuel generator which came with a 5' Lp gas hose and a regulator to fit a 20 Lb tank.  The regulator is a:

G2R150: Two stage Regulator

- Flow rate:150,000Btu/Hr Max. at 11"W.C. outlet pressure(Second stage), LPG.
- Inlet pressure: from 25psig to 250psig
- Safety:Lock out when over flow and over temperature.(connect to GCC or QCC)
- Inlet connection:POL,GCC(QCC) or other thread type of fitting or connection
- Outlet connection:Hose or fitting

Generator is a Firman H08053 Dual fuel

I want to connect it to my quick connect BBQ supply line which is fed from a:

```
CAVAGNA GROUP KOSAN
PART NUMBER: 988LP-03
BTU CAP: 800,000
MAX INPUT: 10 PSI
OUTPUT: 11"WC
```

Is it as simple as having a 30' propane hose made up with a quick connect?

Thanks

Comment: Double-check the markings on that regulator that came with the generator -- it seems rather unlikely to have 250 PSI *output* pressure.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Is the regulator an integral part of the generator? What make and model is said generator?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work, I have a Firman that I would like to do the same with. But haven't been able to get it to start.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the two regulators have the same output setting, and the BBQ supply is fed from a regulator with a high Btu/hr capacity. There are two more things you'll have to work out:

1. Does that 800,000 Btu/hr accommodate all the propane appliances that might operate concurrently?
2. With the added load of the generator drawing gas through the supply intended for BBQ, is the size of the system piping adequate to handle the flows required?

The second question can be more difficult to answer -- you'll need to find out the length, size, and material of the pipe in the gas system and then do some math. A web search for "propane pipe sizing" will turn up results that explain the methods -- for example, El Dorado County in California provides [this](https://www.edcgov.us/Government/building/documents/Gas%20Pipe%20Sizing%20%28Propane%29.pdf) handout which explains the "longest length" method of pipe sizing.